# Sh script not running in crontab but running manually with ./

Tags: linux, cron

I have a .sh script that I've put in crontab with this command:

```
0 * * * * /root/Linux/lansare.sh
```

It doesn't run even though I made the script an executable. I checked it and it has x. I tried before the script to write : #!/bin/sh but it still doesn`t run

If I run it manually like `./lansare.sh` from the folder it works.

Can you please help me make it work from crontab ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you add that line to root's crontab or another user's?

Comment: see what cron logs when it tries to run it. depends on the distribution but there's probably something in `/var/log`, try e.g. `grep -ie cron `/var/log/*`

Comment: What is in your script? how did you edited your crontab? and what is your current user?

Comment: Did the user who owns this crontab get any error messages emailed to them by the cron daemon?

Answer (score 0):

put this in your crontab

```
0 * * * * /root/Linux/lansare.sh >> /root/Linux/lansare.log 2>&1
```

and then read /root/Linux/lansare.log

This way, you'll get to see both the output steams (Stdout and Stderror) and you'll know what's wrong in the script.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different ways to put it in crontab:

1. Did you run `crontab -e` which the starts an editor where you typed `0 * * * * /root/Linux/lansare.sh`?  If so, then make sure you run the `crontab -e` command **as root** because you have your script in `/root` where normal user do not have permissions.
2. Did you put it in `/etc/crontab` or in a file in `/etc/cron.d/`?  If so, then you have **include the username** you want to use to run the script (in your case `root`) in the line. Like this:

   ```
   0 * * * * root /root/Linux/lansare.sh
   #         ^^^^----[here]
   ```